# Convert integer from InFile to OutFile as float in Cobol

Tags: cobol

I have an `InFile.dat` containing some integer values which I store in a record in `SomeFile.cob`. When I add it to the `OutFile.dat` I cannot get the integers to convert to floats.

```
FILE-SECTION.
*> In File:
01 someInt PIC 9. *> eg. 3

*> Out File:
01 PrintLine PIC X(75). *> for writing data to a line

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 someFloat PIC 9V99. 

PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
COMPUTE someFloat = someInt / 1
DISPLAY someFloat *> displays 3.00 (good) 
WRITE PrintLine FROM someFloat *> stored as 300 (not good)
```

How can I store it in the out file as a float?

Comment: 'float' does not mean 'potentially non-integer'; merely having fractional digits does not make something floating point, only _fixed_ point. Floating point means having an _exponent_ (aka scale factor) as _part of each data value_. The COBOL standard does not require floating-point at all, it is up to the 'processor' (implemenation, normally compiler), which you didn't specify. [See e.g. for IBM z-series.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_6.3.0/pg/concepts/cpari09.html) Even the syntax isn't standard before 2002, which TTBOMK isn't widely implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIC 9V99` is *not* a floating point but a fixed-point integer value, that has a *guaranteed*  precision.

It does not store the decimal point "in memory" so it isn't part of your outputfile, which is good (the `v` is the *implied decimal point* which is only in effect on run-time depending on the field definition).

To output this you may use an edited field which is explicit for output (nothing you should do any calculation on):

```
       01 someFixedPoint PIC 9V99.
       01 someEdited     PIC 9.99. *> use "," when DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA

           MOVE someFixedPoint TO someEdited
           WRITE PrintLine FROM someEdited
```